# Javascript to Ruby Encryption

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, html, encryption, cryptography

I have an app using HTML5 caching for an "offline mode".  When the app is offline, data is stored via javascript in localStorage to be sent to the server when the app comes back "online".  I would like to run some of this data through an encryption before sticking it in localStorage in a way that can only be decrypted on the server.

I was thinking that a public/private key would be the way to do this.  Is that a reasonable way to go about things?  Are there any good javascript libraries for handling this sort of thing client-side?  Are there good ruby/rails libraries/gems for handling this server-side?

Comment: Could you please tell more? Why do you need encryption here? If it is to prevent the user from reading the data, he can already do that by editing your JS at runtime. Moreover, the user can store whatever data he wants into the encrypted storage if he has the public key (you can't trust this encrypted content, as it is not signed).

Comment: The js is obfuscated to the point where we are not really worried about a user manipulating it (I know someone really dedicated could, but this level of protection is sufficient for the project's scope).  Mostly just want to add a layer of protection to localStorage to keep it from being read easily, while still allowing the server to receive in user entered values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to encrypt data in localStorage, you can use public key cryptography. Don't generate the keys in JS, do it server side, and send the public key with the page. Unfortunately, I don't know any well tested and maintained crypto library in Javascript.

For the level of security you're aiming at (just a little layer to prevent the user from reading the data), you can choose whatever implementation you want.
On server side, you can use the OpenSSL gem with the class OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.

**For anyone else reading this: Don't use Javascript crypto, [it's bad](http://rdist.root.org/2010/11/29/final-post-on-javascript-crypto/)!**

Answer (score 0):

For handling this client side, there is the [handleStorage](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/handleStorage) plugin for jQuery, which is really easy to use, but is GPL. If you cannot use that due to licensing issues, you can combine the [jStorage](http://www.jstorage.info/) jQuery plugin with the [blowfish](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/blowfish) jQuery plugin.